# Show image from path by python django

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my django project. it will uploads a file in a path outside django' root in server. now I want an function that can retrive that file and show the client. It's nondirect link and is like http://example.com/uploads/{ID}.
now how it's possible. note that uploaded files  are image.

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file1']:
    myfile = request.FILES['file1']
    fileType = request.GET.get('type',None)
    if fileType==None:
        return json_response(65,400)
    if myfile.size > 5*1024*1000:
        return json_response(85,400)
    elif not (myfile.content_type.startswith('image') or myfile.content_type == 'application/pdf'):
        return json_response(185,400)

    fs = FileSystemStorage('../uploads')
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    request.user.file_set.create(name = uploaded_file_url, type = fileType, createdAt = datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a view where the id as URL slug. after that you can find the the file path for the corresponding ID to read the file and send the response. here is the code for reading the file from a path and send as HTTP response

```
with open(valid_image_url, "rb") as f:
     return HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="image/jpeg")
```